# Can't create Jupyter Notebook in a subdirectory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am having issues creating a Jupyter Notebook inside a subdirectory. Instead of creating in the subdirectory, it creates in the root path.

Let me exemplify. Let us suppose that I have the following path structure:[image]

Then, I open `Subdirectory_1` and asks it to create a Notebook.
[image]

But instead of creating it in the `Subdirectory_1`, it creates in the root path.

[image]

And these are the log messages:

[image]

Comment: There was a bug in notebook 5.3. It should be fixed in 5.4, which is out now on PyPI. Conda packages should follow soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @thomas-k mentioned in the comments:

> There was a bug in notebook 5.3. It should be fixed in 5.4, which is out now on PyPI. Conda packages should follow soon.

More info on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/3264).

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js

Try to update or install again the package :

```
conda update -c conda-forge ipywidgets
```

Then this:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

source : [Github](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/186)

Comment: This helped me solve the 404 message. I discovered that there were two `nbconfig` files: one in the `.jupyter` path on my home and other in the anaconda path. Unfortunately, I still can't create a notebook in a subdirectory. Also, thanks for pointing ey to the GitHub repository. I opened an issue there.