# Jupyter Notebook unable to create notebook in non root directory

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After updating Jupyter Notebook (versions below):

```
jupyter                   1.0.0            py36h422fd7e_2
jupyter_client            5.2.1                    py36_0
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py36h6d89b47_1
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py36h56e9d50_0
```

I now cannot create a Python notebook in a directory - other than the root directory I spawned my notebook server.

As an example, if I spawn my server in `\home` but then navigate to `\home\a` and attempt to create a new Python notebook, it automatically redirects me to `\home` in my navigation window and creates the notebook there.  Further, the server gives me the following:

```
[W 14:26:34.925 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/notify.js?v=20180125141725 (::1) 2.00ms referer=http://localhost:1234/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python3
[W 14:26:34.934 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/theme_toggle.js?v=20180125141725 (::1) 2.00ms referer=http://localhost:1234/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python3
[I 14:26:35.025 NotebookApp] Kernel started: d5e26b01-8420-4e07-a74e-35531ce16625
[W 14:26:35.071 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20180125141725 (::1) 2.51ms referer=http://localhost:1234/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python3
[I 14:26:36.818 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel d5e26b01-8420-4e07-a74e-35531ce16625
```

In the prior version (or whatever version I was previously on), I was able to create new notebooks in my current directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create Jupyter Notebook in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429807/cant-create-jupyter-notebook-in-a-subdirectory)

Comment: @LouiseDavies thanks

Comment: duplicate of [Can't create Jupyter Notebook in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429807/cant-create-jupyter-notebook-in-a-subdirectory)